# Firebase Firestore Rules for Large Teams with low read count

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm trying to create a SaaS platform where customers can create organizations and invite other users to their organizations.

At the moment I have these 4/5 collections:

- Users
- Organizations
- - (Team Members)
- - Domains
- - Uptime

The problem I'm facing when querying client-side is that I get insufficient permissions because my queries "potentially include documents that violate my security rules".

For Organizations then there is a simple solution, create a "members" field in each document that contain user uid's and then do `allow read: if request.auth.uid in resource.data.members`. Although I don't like this solution because (1) it doesn't say anything about read/create/update/delete permissions, and (2) I can't keep track of all (future) team members on each document inside the domain and uptime (sub)collections so I have no idea how I could then query those (sub)collections.

I tried to attach some custom tokens (my thought was that I could perform the same permission check on the subcollections if I did like this) and then say, e.g.

```
match /organizations/{organization} {
  allow read: if organization in request.auth.token.organizations;
}
```

But that doesn't work, I also tried to create custom tokens where token key included organization id and value included read/create/update/delete permissions, but it was also unsuccessful due to same insufficient permissions error.

I would really appreciate if someone could help guide me towards the right solution, ideally one that doesn't result in extra "reads" to check permission, because I plan to load many documents at the same time and watch for live changes so that the organization's team members can easily modify the same domain/uptime documents without worrying that they're overwriting each others work.

---

Edit: Code examples of my attempts (I didn't run multiple "allow read" on the same collection, just to show the things I remember trying):

```
const { request } = require("http");

rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    // this works when I do queries like: query(collection(db, 'organizations'), where('members', 'array-contains', uid))
    match /organizations/{document=**} {
        allow read: if request.auth.uid in resource.data.members; // works
        // however, if I try to query subcollections then I cannot do the same, e.g.
        match /domains/{documents=**} {
            // this of course doesn't work unless I store "members" inside the "domains" subcollection which is not an option
            allow read: if request.auth.uid in resource.data.members; // insufficient permissions
        }
    }
    // based on the above problem with querying subcollections, then I tried the following
    // (I use same where members query as above)
    match /organizations/{organization} {
        allow read: if request.auth.uid in organization.members; // insufficient permissions
        allow read: if organization in request.auth.token.organizations; // insufficient permissions
        // if it worked, then my plan was to do something similar to this:
        match /domains/{document=**} {
            allow read: if organization in request.auth.token.organizations; // insufficient permissions
            // or perhaps something like this (although I have no idea how to inject document ID into the request.auth.token key):
            allow read: if 'read-role' in request.auth.token.{organization}.roles; // insufficient permissions
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It is much more likely that someone can help if you show us exactly what you tried for a single approach that you thought should've worked, rather than multiple halves of things you tried. If you created a custom token, show how you did that. What happened when you did that? What did you expect? What was the error message? Show us the code you used to read the data too, and the document you tried to read. All these parts together make a [minimal repro](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), which is really your best best at getting help..

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thanks for the reply, I edited my post with some of my attempts. I'm guessing my custom token attempts fail because the queries would always "potentially include documents that violate the security rules". But I find it really weird that "allow read: if request.auth.uid in organization.members;" resulted in insufficient permissions.